# Stripe best practice, should I have multiple accounts for multiple development/production environments

Tags: stripe-payments

Hope your day is going great.

Simple question but would love reasoning behind the answer if you'd be kind enough to lend some time to this question.

For the payment platform Stripe, what are the best practices regarding single or multiple accounts for multiple development/production environments? Should I have one account per environment or should I have just one account that makes use of test mode?

Thanks for your time

Comment: It's up to you really. Each Stripe account has Test mode and Live mode and it's normal to just use 1 account if you have have 2 environments. But if you system is bigger and more complex, nothing can stop you to have multiple accounts, using each account Test mode for your environments, then only 1 account Live mode for Production